# Proving that something is a Gaussian Process

Tags: machine-learning, inference, gaussian-process

$f \sim GP(\mathbf{m}, k_\theta)$ is a Gaussian Process, where $\mathbf{m} \sim GP(0, k_\eta)$ is another Gaussian Process.

I need to show that this is equivalent to a having a Gaussian Process with mean 0 and a covariance function which I have to figure out. I'm not quite sure how to manipulate covariances... here's what I've got so far:

$f$ GP $\implies $ for $x_1,...,x_n$, $(f(x_1),...,f(x_n)) \sim N(\mathbf{m}, k_\theta)$

$m$ GP $\implies $ for $x_1,...,x_n$, $(\mathbf{m}(x_1),...,\mathbf{m}(x_n)) \sim N(0, k_\eta)$

and I'm currently trying to figure out $\mathrm{Cov}(f(x_i), f(x_j)) = \mathbb{E}[f(x_i)f(x_j)]$ to show that it's somehow related to $k_\theta$ and $k_\eta$ but I'm not sure how to express it algebraically at all.

Comment: Note that $f$ is the sum of two Gaussian processes: $GP(0, k_{\theta})$ and $GP(0, k_{\eta})$.